# Computing the sum of an alternating power series

Tags: summation, power-series

I'm asked to find the sum of a power series [image]
for all x in the interior of the domain of convergence, which I found to be [-1,1]. The question also gives the hint to take the second derivative of the series which I found to be [image]

I understand the idea of differentiating term by term to find the answer but I am unsure of what to do with the (-1)^n

If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do successive terms of your new series have constant ratio?

Comment: @EricTowers Yes ignoring the alternating sign the terms have a constant ratio of x^2

Comment: Well, $-x^2$, so it is a geometric series...

Comment: @EricTowers Got it thank you

Answer (score 1):

Deriving term by term, we obtain the series:
$$ 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n x^{2n-2} = 2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} x^{2n} = -2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-x^2)^n  $$
This is a geometric series, whose sum is easily obtained. Then, you can evaluate the former series integrating two times (say, over the interval $(0,t)$).

Comment: I understand thank you